# How to calculate letterSpacing for TextView from sketch values?

Tags: android, textview, sketch-3

In design I have a text field with 16 as text size and 0.6 as character spacing

But, if I set this value for `android:letterSpacing` attribute of `TextView` spacing will be much more larger than in design.

So, what is the way to convert sketch value to android value?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to Romain Guy, Android uses the "1 em = font size" definition, so you'd just do

```
setLetterSpacing(characterSpacing / textSize)
```

...just make sure those values are in the same unit (dp vs px)

Comment: Thank you very much! I just checked it and it works! :)

Comment: not working for me, spacing is smaller than in sketch

Comment: This is documented here https://material.io/design/typography/the-type-system.html but specifies sp for the font size, so: `Android letter spacing = Sketch letter spacing / font size in sp`

Comment: Right. Zeplin does with the same method.

Answer (score 3):

If Sketch provides the letter spacing value in Points, then the following is the conversion:

```
float textSizePx = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,  textSizeInSp, displayMetrics);
float letterSpacingPx = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PT,  sketchLetterSpacing, displayMetrics); 
float androidLetterSpacing = letterSpacingPx / textSizePx
return androidLetterSpacing;
```

Answer (score 2):

Material design 2 uses `em` as the unit for letter spacing on Android, [and the following conversion ratio for Sketch values need to be applied](https://m2.material.io/design/typography/the-type-system.html#type-scale):

> (Tracking from Sketch / font size
> in sp) = letter spacing

To clarify, here is an example for Jetpack Compose:

```
fontSize = 14.sp,
letterSpacing = (1.25 / 14).em
```

`1.25` is the Sketch value and `14` is the font size in `sp`, but note the unit is converted to `em`.

Answer (score -2):

Check out android:textScaleX

Depending on how much spacing you need, this might help. That's the only thing remotely related to letter-spacing in the TextView.

Comment: Irrelevant. For instance, in Sketch I have 0.58. It means that I have 0 + .58. So it spacing should be bigger than original ( 0 ) spacing. If I use textScaleX, so I change scale. In this case 0.58 < 1, so scaling will be less, than original.