# Why sources letter spacing is different from documentation in Android material design?

Tags: android, material-design, typography, android-fonts, android-typeface

I am confusing about `android:letterSpacing` attribute. Here https://material.io/design/typography/the-type-system.html#type-scale  says that Body1 has letter spacing 0.25px , but in source code it shows 0.0178571429

[image]

If i need letter spacing 0.25px (or 0.15px or any other) what value should i use (or how can i calculate right value?)? 
`<item name="android:letterSpacing">0.0178571429</item>`
 or 
`<item name="android:letterSpacing">0.25</item>`

Answer (score 0):

I found answer here [How to calculate letterSpacing for TextView from sketch values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39100969/how-to-calculate-letterspacing-for-textview-from-sketch-values) . If  just divide 0.25/14 = 0.0178571429 we get letterSpacing attribute value